# Break role inheritance and assign unique permissions for only a specific group

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have created an addin . I want when the default page loads , so i have to use javascript , to assign unique permissions to only two groups :

Leave Request Members
Leave Request Managers

Permissions should be assigned in whole add-in. So in all the lists

Can anyone help me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Break role inheritance:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function()  
    {  
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', breakInheritance);  
    });  

    function breakInheritance()  
    {  
        //Get the client context and list object    
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('DemoList');  
        //Break inheritence    
        oList.breakRoleInheritance(true, false);  
        //Load the client context and execcute the batch    
        clientContext.load(oList);  
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(QuerySuccess, QueryFailure);  
    }  

    function QuerySuccess()  
    {  
        console.log("Inheritence has been broken.");  
    }  

    function QueryFailure(sender, args)  
    {  
        console.log('Request failed' + args.get_message());  
    }  
</script>
```

Assign permission to Group:

```
function ChangePermissions(groupMembershipID,permissionLevel) {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = clientContext.get_web();
        //Get Role Definition by name
        var roleDef = web.get_roleDefinitions().getByName(permissionLevel);
        var roleDefBinding = SP.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.newObject(clientContext);
        // Add the role to the role definiiton binding.
        roleDefBinding.add(roleDef);
        // Get the RoleAssignmentCollection for the web.
        var assignments = web.get_roleAssignments();
        //Get the role assignment for the group using Group  's membership id
        var groupRoleAssignment = assignments.getByPrincipalId(groupMembershipID);
        groupRoleAssignment.importRoleDefinitionBindings(roleDefBinding);
        groupRoleAssignment.update();
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            alert("Permissions changed !");
        },
                function (sender, args) {
                    console.log(args.get_message());
                });
    });
}
```

Refer:
[Change Permission of a SharePoint Group using Javascript CSOM](https://unnieayilliath.com/2015/07/28/change-permission-of-a-sharepoint-group-using-javascript-csom/)